# Parse push notifications on Ionic/Cordova: Invalid device token

Tags: cordova, parse-platform

I am trying to set up Parse push notifications in my ionic app. I currently am doing:

```
var parseInstallationId = Parse._getInstallationId().then(function(uuid){
   alert(typeof uuid);
        var d = {
          "deviceType": platform,  
          "deviceToken": uuid,
          "channels": [""]
        }
        alert(JSON.stringify(d));

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/installations/',
            headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'parse-id','X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'parse-rest-id'},
            data: d
          }).then(...)
```

I continue to get 'invalid device token: 8493-4389-4839...'. I am guessing the number is in the wrong format or just the wrong number all together.

I tried using some repos like https://github.com/grrrian/phonegap-parse-plugin but was getting build errors so wanted to go for the api.

I've been going in circles for hours. I was told I needed to create an Installation object, subscribe to a channel and set a user to that object. My partners set up the backend and profile stuff on xcode. So just need to connect the actual code in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up solving it as such:

```
var parseInstallationId = Parse._getInstallationId().then(function(inId){

      var d = {
        "deviceType": platform,  
        "deviceToken": registrationId,
        "channels": [""],
        "installationId":inId
      }
      var userId = Parse.User.current().id; 
      d['user'] = {
        "__type": "Pointer",
        "className": "_User",
        "objectId": userId
      }
      if(platform === 'android'){
        d.pushType = 'gcm';
      }

      $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/installations/',
        headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'XXXX','X-Parse-REST-API-Key':'XXXX'},
        data: d
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
          installationId = response;
        }, 
        function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log('pushInstallation error: ', response);
      });
    })
```

I get the installation id, and save that to the object passed into Parse. The registrationId comes from using:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
      android: {
          senderID: "XXXX"
      },
      ios: {
          alert: "true",
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
      },
      windows: {}
    });

push.on('registration', function(data) {
      User.pushInstallation(platform, data.registrationId);
})
```

This is from https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: Just a related note: in general if you initialize Parse.Push from the javascript side, you won't be able to handle cold starts via notification. You'll likely get a crash message on Android when a notification arrives and your app isn't already running. This is because the Android init sequence is Application --> ... handle push ... --> launch Activity to load WebView and start javascript subsystem. At the "handle push" phase, because we are dealing with Parse.Push and Android Parse SDK has not been initialized, we have a crash.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I will have to ask here. Are you using the Javascript SDK with your ionic app? Did you only install the phonegap push plugin and use just the code above (I'm assuming in your app.js ) to set up the push notifications? Care to setup a guide for your soultion for us noobs :) ??

Comment: I can set up a guide soon. But in short, I am using angularjs and used https://github.com/driftyco/ionic for angular and ionic setup. Then install the phonegap push plugin. By calling push.on('registration') (see code below), that will open up the notification permission modal. The first code below I set up in a service, the second is in a controller. You can put them anywhere you like.

Answer (score 0):

While developing [parse-push-plugin](https://github.com/taivo/parse-push-plugin) I found that for ionic projects, you're dealing with 2 different installationId's:

1. `Parse._getInstallationId()` is generated by the Parse Javascript sdk, and it has nothing to do with your device. This installationId exists even on your desktop browser and Parse does not store it in the database as an Installation object.
2. The device installationId that is stored in Installation objects in the database and used to target push are generated by native Parse SDKs. On Android, it's `ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getInstallationId()`. On iOS, it's `[PFInstallation currentInstallation].installationId`

Additionally, `deviceToken` is a whole different beast. InstallationId is generated by whichever Parse SDK you are using and it's generated entirely on your machine. Device token is only obtained by asking registering with GCM or APNS.

So in your original question, the error is 2 fold: using the wrong installation id and using it as a deviceToken.